# Is it possible to have an assertion in the @AfterAll method?

Tags: java, junit5, junit-jupiter

I would like to have an assertion in the `@AfterAll` method after aggregating data from a `@ParameterizedTest`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work because the exceptions thrown within the `@AfterAll` method are not propagated up.

```java
class ExampleTest {

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAll() {
        throw new RuntimeException("will not fail the test");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to have an assertion after all test methods have completed?

**Edit:** it appears to be a problem with Intellij. I reported it as a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292853/Intellij-does-not-propagate-errors-thrown-in-JUnit-5%27s-@AfterAll).

Comment: Did you try to make it non-static with annotation on class `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`?

Comment: It is not a good idea to make assertion in `@AfterAll` IMO. This is used for teardown  such as closing resource, connection, etc.